# Twitter login with cURL

Tags: php, curl, twitter

So i have this script which utilizes cURL to log into twitter. The problem is however, while the script does work, it only creates a temporary session, and the user does not stay logged in. How would i go about modifying it to ensure the user does in fact stay logged in?

```
 # First call gets hidden form field authenticity_token
 # and session cookie

 $ch = curl_init();
 $sTarget = "https://twitter.com/";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://twitter.com/");
 $html = curl_exec($ch);

 # parse authenticity_token out of html response
 preg_match('/<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token"\/>/', $html, $match);
 $authenticity_token = $match[1];

 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";

 # set post data
 $sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

 # second call is a post and performs login
 $sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

 # display server response
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use the cookie-jar option.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
```

Basically with the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option curl uses to load cookie from the file during sending a request. And with the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option curl uses to save(from response) the cookie into the defined file.

Comment: Hmm, still no joy with either :/

Comment: Your `$password` might have special characters. Use `urlencode()` over the password to escape those. Also, enable the VERBOSE mode of curl to inspect the responses that you have received from the twitter. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`